# FluentAssertions: int.Should().Equals returns wrong result?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, fluent-assertions

I just start to use Moq & FluentAssertions and find this:

```
results.Results.Count.Should().Equals(1);
```

in the code, results.Results return a list of class List. In the test setup, I set it as results.Results.Count = 3 (I can see this # is correct in debug too). But somehow, the above .Equals test passed. Then I changed it to

```
results.Results.Count.Should().Equals("1");
```

It still passed. It will fail if I use

```
results.Results.Count.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(1);
```

So, the question is:

**what results.Results.Count.Should().Equals("1") compare? why it passed?**

Thanks

Comment: I don't think `.Should()` is a part of `Moq`. EDIT: yea, i can't find it [in the documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/Moq)

Comment: thanks. changed it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
results.Results.Count.Should().Equals(1);
```

is calling the `Equals` method inherited from `Object` on the object returned by `Should()` which returns a `bool` which is being ignored. You need to use `Be` or `Equal` e.g.

```
results.Results.Count.Should().Be(1);
```

Comment: This is correct. Since FluentAssertions 6.3 this potential misuse of `Equals` is fixed. See changelog: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/releases/tag/6.3.0 and the issue: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1705